# How to pop out a Firefox window without an address bar or status?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

How to pop out a Firefox window without an address bar or status, basically what i need is a bar minimum window that renders my html.

Comment: Pages like that are so annoying..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, it's possible in neither Firefox nor Internet Explorer any more for security reasons.

If you're building a web application, you could try [Mozilla Prism](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Prism):

> Prism is a simple XULRunner based browser that hosts web applications without the normal web browser user interface. Prism is based on a concept called Site Specific Browsers (SSB). An SSB is an application with an embedded browser designed to work exclusively with a single web application. It doesn’t have the menus, toolbars and accoutrements of a normal web browser.

If you need to serve web pages to the public, it's not for you, though. It needs client-side installation.

Comment: Hi Pekka, yep i need this for a private web app.

Comment: @Babiker then check out whether Prism is for you. As far as I can see, it's your best shot. Microsoft used to have a concept of "Hypertext Applications" (HTA) too but I don't know whether that is still alive - haven't heard of it since 2004 or so.

Comment: OMG, where have you been for the past 4 years :D .  This is wonderful i been looking for something like this for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.parent.open( 'http://www.google.com',
    '','toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,' +
    'scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=400,height=300').focus();
    return false;">
Open Window
</a>
```

Comment: This is not supported in modern browsers.