# Javascript not excecuted in Firefox

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open new popup window without address bars in firefox & IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909645/open-new-popup-window-without-address-bars-in-firefox-ie)

I have the following code which works in ie(no addressbar, status bar, etc but not firefox... any suggestions?

```
    function popUpDetails(trackNum) {
        var newWindow = (window.open('popUpDetails.aspx?trackNum=' + trackNum, 'Title', 'width=540,height=265, location=no, menubar=no, status=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, modal=no'));
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of this: [How to pop out a Firefox window without an address bar or status?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924851/how-to-pop-out-a-firefox-window-without-an-address-bar-or-status)

Comment: seems to be same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909645/open-new-popup-window-without-address-bars-in-firefox-ie

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is supported in Mozilla. I believe instead of using a popup window you should be using colorbox a jQuery Lightbox. http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Comment: window.open is totally supported by Firefox (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)

Comment: I don't think sushil meant that window.open is unsupported, but that hiding the address bar when doing so is unsupported. Which is correct.