# How can i create webpage with out address/menu and tool bar

Tags: javascript

How can i create web page with out address/menu and tool bar.

I want the page to load without address/menu and tool bar.

Can someone please help to create webpage in asp.net or html using javascript.

I tried using javascript by using following code, but this warns that this page is closing i dont warning to be display.

```
a.htm

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init()
{
var window_dimensions = "toolbars=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes";  
window.opener=self;
window.close();
window.open("b.htm","_blank", window_dimensions);  
window.moveTo(0,0);  
window.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height-100); 
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
```

Comment: So you want to open a new window using JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

These are standard security restrictions today, put there for good reason.  Don't try to work-around them.  If you think you have a need to do so, I'd re-review your requirements and reasons for doing so.  If it is truly a need, you may need to consider a custom desktop (non-web-browser) application.  This could still be a HTML-based application, but a custom desktop "browser" would be required.

See also: [How to pop out a Firefox window without an address bar or status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924851/how-to-pop-out-a-firefox-window-without-an-address-bar-or-status)  (This includes excellent details for a custom desktop "browser", and follows the above recommendation.)